# How to free up a stuck main water valve whose handle spins freely?

Tags: plumbing, valve

Main Water valve will not open or close. Feels 3/4 closed. I desperately need it open. Handle free spins.

Please help! No water in two days.

Comment: Does the stem of the valve spin free or is it just the handle? Did you just close the valve to do some repair and it only opened about 1/4 before it started free spin? Could you attach a picture of the valve?

Comment: If the stem of the valve spins, without opening or closing the valve, then the stem of the valve may be broken off at the gate. You should call a plumber who can replace the valve. When you call, tell him/her what the problem is, so they can coordinate with the water company  or bring  their own curb box key to shut off the main valve..

Comment: @d.george: That looks like an answer.

Comment: I have had old gate valves break loose at the stem from the threaded gate, in a few cases I have been able to get the stem back into the gate to make the valve operate but it will need to be replaced because the next time it is closed this happens again.

Comment: "Main Water valve" sounds like something the water utility/city would be responsible for, but maybe this has other meanings outside of the US?

Comment: Main water valve - generally there are two of these , one is on the Utility Side and the Other on the Residence side. The water company can replace either , one normally has a charge $$ (residence side) the other does not have a charge $ - utility side.